# Use the tail bound to estimate the probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The heights of trees in a particular forest follow a normal distribution with mean 60 feet and standard deviation 10 feet. The tail bound for the standard normal distribution (i.e. X ∼ N(0, 1)) is:

P(X>x)

Use the tail bound to estimate the fraction of trees in this forest that have height 85 feet or higher. Write your estimate as an inequality.

I thought I just plug in 85 as x, but then what do I need mean and SD for? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, then $\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$. Thus, if you want to find out how a tree of height 85 drawn from a mean 60 and standard deviation 10 distribution, the mapped value would be $\frac{85-60}{10}$. So, you get $P(\text{tree height} > 85) = P(N(0,1) > \frac{85-60}{10})$. And then you can apply the tail bound.

Comment: then I plug in 2.5 into the tail bound for x?